# Верная установка Interception by Francisco Lopes

Tags: python, клавиатура, драйвер, мышь

Всё никак не могу установить драйвер Interception.
Он необходим для одной библиотеки Python.

http://www.oblita.com/interception.html

Там есть гайд, но для меня он не очень понятен, поэтому после его установки у меня перестала работать клавиатура и мышь, пришлось восстанавливать систему.

> **Original**
> Second, you must link against the Interception library, which is provided in the assets, or you may build it from sources.
> Third, you must include interception.h in your applications.
> **Google Translate**
> Во-вторых, вы должны создать ссылку на библиотеку перехвата, которая предоставляется в активах, или вы можете создать ее из источников .
> В-третьих, вы должны включить interception.h в свои приложения.

Что значит создать ссылку на библиотеку перехвата?
В какие приложения я должен добавить interception.h?

Comment: *you must link against the Interception library* - надо прилинковать библиотеку. Почитайте про процесс сборки компилируемых приложений.

Comment: _Он необходим для одной библиотеки Python._ - ну расскажи немного про нее, что это за библиотека, откуда ее брать и т.д.

Comment: @hoefling Библиотека называется AutoHotPy, нужна мне для имитации более "хардварного" клика без дополнительных устройств (это по сути - драйвер), ибо игра не реагирует на обычные программные клики. Interception заявлен как обязательный в этой библиотеке, а установить я его верно не смог, после установки у меня заблокировалась клавиатура и мышь, думаю, что это была неверная установка

Comment: AutoHotPy вызывает `interception.dll` через `ctypes`, так что ни компилировать, ни линковать ничего не надо, нужна только сама dll. Скачай `Interception.zip` с [гитхаба](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/releases/tag/v1.0.1), распакуй, запусти `command line installer\install-interception.exe`. Скопируй библиотеку `library\x64\interception.dll` в директорию, где у тебя лежит `InterceptionWrapper.py`, готово. Либо, если у тебя 32-битный Python, копируй `library\x86\interception.dll`.

Comment: @hoefling Спасибо огромное, это то, что нужно было, всё прекрасно работает :). Только жаль, что не помог этот "хардварный клик" моей задаче, так что это было всё зря :(

Comment: Бывает. А что за задача, перехват эвентов клавиатуры-мыши? Типа кейлоггер на питоне? Есть `pynput`, например.